Rust Timeout reading serial port
I'm new to rust (with a lot of experaince in c and python)
I'm trying to read a serial port rpi pico.
When I use a terminal the data is streamed

I make sure that the comport is not used elsewhere
Here is the code i'm trying to run
use std::io::{self, Read, Write};
use std::time::Duration;
use serialport::{DataBits, StopBits};


fn main() {
let port_name: &str = "com4";
let baud_rate: u32 = 115200;

let port = serialport::new(port_name, baud_rate)
    .stop_bits(StopBits::One)
    .data_bits(DataBits::Eight)
    .timeout(Duration::from_millis(1000))
    .open();
match port {
    Ok(mut port) => {
        let mut serial_buf: Vec<u8> = vec![0; 1000];
        println!("Receiving data on {} at {} baud:", &port_name, &baud_rate);
        loop {
            match port.read(serial_buf.as_mut_slice()) {
                Ok(t) => {
                    io::stdout().write_all(&serial_buf[..t]).unwrap();
                    io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
                }
                Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::TimedOut => println!("Port timedout"),
                Err(e) => eprintln!("{:?}", e),
            }
        }
    }
    Err(e) => {
        eprintln!("Failed to open \"{}\". Error: {}", port_name, e);
        ::std::process::exit(1);
    }
    }
}

When running this code all read are ended in timeout.
I'm running the code on a windows 11 laptop
And another qustion, what is the difference if I make the port var as mutuable?
Thank you

https://github.com/serialport/serialport-rs/tree/main/examples

My code is based on that example code

what example ? I give a directory full of examples, which one did you pick ?

The recive data example.
